# Make AutoMapper's Map ignore some properties?

Tags: c#, automapper

My model object has some properties for lazy loaded collections and AutoMapper is for these collections to be loaded even when I don't need them (this is causing thousands of query executions in my DB). Is it possible to make AutoMapper ignore some properties when I call `Mapper.Map`?

```
public TTarget Adapt<TSource, TTarget>(TSource source)
{
    return Mapper.Map<TTarget>(source);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**With AutoMapper 8.0 the previous answer no longer works.**

[8.0 Upgrade Guide - ForSourceMember Ignore](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/8.0-Upgrade-Guide.html?highlight=ignore%20source#forsourcemember-ignore)

So the adjusted answer would be:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, Doctor>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LastName))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
      .ForSourceMember(src=> src.FirstName, opt => opt.DoNotValidate());
```

---

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }    
}

public class Doctor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set;}
}
```

Here is how I ignore a property with Automapper (I've included how to ignore both in the source and destination object):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, Doctor>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LastName))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
      .ForSourceMember(src=> src.FirstName, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>()
                .ForMember(b=>b.SomeMember, c=>c.Ignore());
```

Comment: Could you maybe give a more "real world" sample? It's difficult to figure out what those two arguments in ForMember() are supposed to be, i.e. is c=>c.Ignore a flag, or a property that needs to be ignored?

Comment: It's a MemberConfigurationExpression on TSource.  You have to use the actual types of the objects being mapped, which you haven't given examples of.  SomeMember would be the name of a property on TTarget that you want to ignore.

Answer (score 2):

With AutoMapper 8.0 @Prabu's answer no longer works.

[8.0 Upgrade Guide - ForSourceMember Ignore](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/8.0-Upgrade-Guide.html?highlight=ignore%20source#forsourcemember-ignore)

So the adjusted answer would be:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, Doctor>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LastName))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
      .ForSourceMember(src=> src.FirstName, opt => opt.DoNotValidate());
```